# CSS Fade out others

Tags: css, hover

Hello I am trying to create a hover effect so when someone hovers over an image withing an LI element this image stays full opacity but the oitehr LI elements fade out slightly. I know this can be done but currently my code is making everything fade out.

Please find a fiddle below my code.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

```
.imageWrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.imageWrapper:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: background 0.3s linear;
}

.cpClientIcon {
  /*
  .cpImageWithTitle {
    .title {
      @include opacity(0);
      transition:opacity 0.3s linear;
    }
  }
*/
}

.cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:after {
  background: red;
}

.cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:hover, .cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:focus, .cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:active, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:hover, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:focus, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:active, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:hover, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:focus, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:active {
  /*
        .title {
          @include opacity(1);
        }
*/
}

.cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:hover .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:focus .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:hover .imageWrapper:active .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:hover .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:focus .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:focus .imageWrapper:active .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:hover .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:focus .imageWrapper:after, .cpClientIcon:active .imageWrapper:active .imageWrapper:after {
  background: transparent;
}

/* Clients Page */
.cpClientIcon {
  background: #fff;
}

.cpClientIcon.ClientIcon {
  width: 100%;
}

.cpClientIcon.ClientIcon ul li {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.cpClientIcon.ClientIcon ul li.imageWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.cpClientIcon.ClientIcon ul li.imageWrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  left: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.cpClientIcon.ClientIcon ul li.imageWrapper:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cpClientIcon.ClientIcon ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dfLk3gy5/

Comment: you can set a hover to the parent element and use it for the child that would look like this .parent:hover .child{styles;}  ... you can not affect siblings or parents by hover only child elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your hover rule for the `UL` to set all child `LI` elements to the desired faded out opacity, then set a hover rule for the `LI` to set opacity back to fully opaque:

```
ul:hover li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul:hover li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kgow697h/

Comment: Your the man. Thank you for something so simple it proved to be tricky ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) too :

```css
 li a {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   display: inline-block;
   width:100%;
 }
 
 li * {
   mix-blend-mode: soft-light;
 }
 
 li:hover * {
   mix-blend-mode: unset;
 }
li {display:inline-block;width:20%;}
img {max-width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="stPage st">
    <div class="gpClientIcons">
        <div class="cpClientIcon ClientIcon">
            <ul>
                <li class="imageWrapper"> <a href="/work/angostura-1919">
                    <img src="http://good.dev.good-creative.com/sites/default/files/styles/client_logo/public/CLIENT_LOGOS_WHITE_BG_24_ANGOSTURA.png?itok=TxAkk1y-"/>
                              </a>
 <a href="/work/angostura-1919"><span>View Case Study</span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="imageWrapper"> <a href="/work/fyne-ales">
                    <img src="http://good.dev.good-creative.com/sites/default/files/styles/client_logo/public/03_1.png?itok=NRCjw1SJ"/>
                              </a>
 <a href="/work/fyne-ales"><span>View Case Study</span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="imageWrapper"> <a href="/work/glengoyne">
                    <img src="http://good.dev.good-creative.com/sites/default/files/styles/client_logo/public/01_.png?itok=ib3J3BkM"/>
                              </a>
 <a href="/work/glengoyne"><span>View Case Study</span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="imageWrapper"> <a href="/work/okells">
                    <img src="http://good.dev.good-creative.com/sites/default/files/styles/client_logo/public/01_.png?itok=ib3J3BkM"/>
                              </a>
 <a href="/work/okells"><span>View Case Study</span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="imageWrapper"> <a href="/work/rrspink-sons">
                              <img src="http://good.dev.good-creative.com/sites/default/files/styles/client_logo/public/03_1.png?itok=NRCjw1SJ">
                              </a>
 <a href="/work/rrspink-sons"><span>View Case Study</span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="imageWrapper"> <a href="/work/tamdhu">
                              <img src="http://good.dev.good-creative.com/sites/default/files/styles/client_logo/public/01_.png?itok=ib3J3BkM">
                              </a>
 <a href="/work/tamdhu"><span>View Case Study</span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it can be done for any element inside li or only to img : https://jsfiddle.net/dfLk3gy5/1/